# Mismatch of rigid type variables

Tags: haskell

I have following Haskell code that failed on `Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a1’` error:

```
bar :: [Int] -> (a -> Int -> a) -> a -> a
bar ns fp ap = snd $ foldl fn (fp, ap) ns
  where fn :: ((a -> Int -> a), a) -> Int -> ((a -> Int -> a), a)
        fn (f, x) i = (fp, (f x (i + length(ns))))
```

Here's the detailed error message:

```
t.hs:4:24: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a1’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          bar :: forall a. [Int] -> (a -> Int -> a) -> a -> a
        at t.hs:1:8
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fn :: forall a1.
                (a1 -> Int -> a1, a1) -> Int -> (a1 -> Int -> a1, a1)
        at t.hs:3:15
      Expected type: a1 -> Int -> a1
        Actual type: a -> Int -> a
    • In the expression: fp
      In the expression: (fp, (f x (i + length (ns))))
      In an equation for ‘fn’:
          fn (f, x) i = (fp, (f x (i + length (ns))))
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: a1 (bound at t.hs:4:16)
        f :: a1 -> Int -> a1 (bound at t.hs:4:13)
        fn :: (a1 -> Int -> a1, a1) -> Int -> (a1 -> Int -> a1, a1)
          (bound at t.hs:4:9)
        ap :: a (bound at t.hs:2:11)
        fp :: a -> Int -> a (bound at t.hs:2:8)
        bar :: [Int] -> (a -> Int -> a) -> a -> a (bound at t.hs:2:1)
```

I was thinking that **`fp`** parameter of function **`bar`** has the same type of **`f`** parameter of function **`fn`** in `where` clause of function **`bar`** (they all have type `(a -> Int -> a)`), however `ghci` treated them as different  types (`a` and `a1`).

I tried to remove type signature of function **`fn`** then the code could be compiled successfully.

```
bar :: [Int] -> (a -> Int -> a) -> a -> a
bar ns fp ap = snd $ foldl fn (fp, ap) ns
  where fn (f, x) i = (fp, (f x (i + length(ns))))
```

My question is: Why the extra type signature of **`fn`** doesn't work? isn't the type system intelligent enough to infer that both **`fp`** and **`f`** could have same types? (especially when **`fn`** is inside scope of **`bar`**).

Comment: You need to enable `ScopedTypeVariables` (and add an explicit forall to the type signature) - otherwise the two type signatures refer to distinct type variables which both happen to be named `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a` in the signature for `fn` isn't recognized as the same `a` in the signature for `bar`. The only way to get this thing to work is with [`ScopedTypeVariables`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

bar :: forall a. [Int] -> (a -> Int -> a) -> a -> a
bar ns fp ap = snd $ foldl fn (fp, ap) ns
  where fn :: ((a -> Int -> a), a) -> Int -> ((a -> Int -> a), a)
        fn (f, x) i = (fp, (f x (i + length(ns))))
```

Alternately, you can just not have a type annotation for `fn` and let the compiler infer it.